# How to return a string without quotes Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, return, quotes, radix

I've got to write a single-input module that can convert decimals to Bukiyip (some ancient language with a counting base of 3 or 4). For the purpose of the assignment, we only need to work with base 3.

I've written some code that does this, but it returns my Bukiyip number with quotes, leaving me with an answer such as '110' for 12.

Please help me understand how to work around this? I'm new to Python and keen to learn so explanations will be really appreciated.

```
def bukiyip_to_decimal(num):
    convert_to_string = "012"
    if num < 3:
        return convert_to_string[num]
    else:
        return bukiyip_to_decimal(num//3) + convert_to_string[num%3]
```

I've also tried the following, but get errors.

```
    else:
        result = bukiyip_to_decimal(num//3) + convert_to_string[num%3]
        print(int(result))
```

Comment: Those are *quotes*, not apostrophes. You mean your function returns a string, and not an integer?

Comment: Note that `110` would be a *decimal* value, one hundred and ten. You are creating a representation in an alternative notation, why is a string not good enough here? How are you printing the output? In other words, can you tell us about your larger problem here before everyone jumps in and just tells you to use `int(result)`?

Comment: Hi @MartijnPieters, yeah I think that's what I'm getting wrong.

Comment: If you just use `print()` to write the result to your console, you'd not get those quotes included, because then the actual string value is written out. So `print(bukiyip_to_decimal(12))` won't show the quotes (which are part of the string literal representation, useful for debugging).

Comment: @MartijnPieters you've answered it! I see where to fix the error - thank you very much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I actually need everything to sit in the module and so I can't see how print(bukiyip_to_decimal(12)) or int(result) would work?

Comment: I didn't tell you to print *in* the function; I told you to print the returned value from the function.. You broke the recursive calls by not returning anything anymore.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you *call* this function. You didn't show us where in your question, you never showed us how you got the result with quotes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you're absolutely right. I just checked the call function and it uses the print function so returning the string was fine. Silly mistake, sorry about that and thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are either echoing the return value in your interpreter, including the result in a container (such as a list, dictionary, set or tuple), or directly producing the `repr()` output for your result.

Your function (rightly) returns a *string*. When echoing in the interpreter or using the `repr()` function you are given a *debugging-friendly representation*, which for strings means Python will format the value in a way you can copy and paste right back into Python to reproduce the value. That means that the quotes are included.

Just *print the value itself*:

```
>>> result = bukiyip_to_decimal(12)
>>> result
'110'
>>> print(result)
110
```

or use it in other output:

```
>>> print('The Bukiyip representation for 12 is {}'.format(result))
The Bukiyip representation for 12 is 110
```

Comment: what to do, if return only true/false without any quotes ?? like a = true/false; return a. note that 't' in 'true' or 'f' in 'false' must be small.

Comment: @Andrew: not sure what you are asking. Are you saying you are seeing `false` or `true` echoed in your REPL session, or you *want* to see that echoed? If the first, try using `type()` on the object to see what kind of class that is. It most likely has a `__repr__` method that returns either `false` or `true`. For the latter: give your type a `__repr__` method.

Answer (score 0):

`int()` doesn't work? The quotes are not for decoration, you see. They are part of the string literal representation. `"hello"` is a string. It is not `hello` with quotes. A bare `hello` is an identifier, a name. So you don't wanna strip quotes from a string, which doesn't make any sense. What you want is a `int`.

Comment: Hi @CPanda, thanks for the advice. I haven't been able to get it to work with int() and I assume it's because I'm putting it in the wrong place. I don't understand how to go from 'bukiyip_to_decimal(num//3) + convert_to_string[num%3]' to returning/printing an integer?

Comment: Is the `+` for concatenation? If it is then `return int(bukiyip_to_decimal(num//3) + convert_to_string[num%3])`

Comment: just checked the call option like Martjin suggested and realised the solution was right in front of me. Thank you for all your help!